# FileStream files won't deleted after records deleteion

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am working in sql server 2016 with Filestream attribute column.
I have a column with filestream attribute activated on it. when I insert a reacord in TSQL , the associated file is created in Filestream container folder which is correct. but the problem is that when I delete a row , the assoicated file in filestream container remains and won't be deleted. as far as I know this shouldn't happen and the file is completely related to its record, so why doesn't it delete?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unneeded filestream container files are physically deleted by a separate background garbage collection process. The files will eventually be deleted to reclaim the storage, just not in real time.

You can force garbage collection to occur immediately using [`sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/filestream-and-filetable-sp-filestream-force-garbage-collection).

Comment: ... and, if I remember correctly, we also need to cycle the transaction log (either a transaction log backup or if in simple recovery a checkpoint occurs).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, yep, that's called out in the GC doc link I referenced.